# How to re-populate a form?

Tags: php, forms, wordpress

I have a user form that creates a drop down menu in Wordpress php. The form clears after it's submitted. How can I re-populate the form, when the edit pencil icon is clicked so the original info can be edited? As it is, because the form is cleared, it starts another menu.
There is one category and multiple names.

Thank you...if you need info, I will post it. I'm trying...
-A

I'm having a problem with this...as I mentioned, there is an "edit button" that creates a stupid edit form that some guy designed. I would like to repopulate the original form users filled out. I'm almost there. The info is is filled in boxes but they randomly overlay the drop down menu. It's not hitting inside the original form.  "pp-website-edit" is the name of the "edit button".

```
  <div class="pp-website-edit">
                <form id="cat-edit-<?php echo $x; ?>" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="edit-category" value="<?php echo $indicat; ?>">
                <INPUT TYPE="image" SRC="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/themes/nebula/neb-style/images/arrow_045_small.png" HEIGHT="14" WIDTH="14" BORDER="0" ALT="Submit Form">
                </form>
            </div>



              <div class="pp-website-edit">
                                <form id="wat-edit" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="edit-website" value="1">
                                <input type="hidden" name="ed-w-cat" value="<?php echo $indicat; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="ed-w-label" value="<?php echo $finalresult[$y][name]; ?>">
                                <input type="hidden" name="ed-w-url" value="<?php echo $finalresult[$y][url]; ?>">
                                <INPUT TYPE="image" SRC="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/themes/nebula/neb-style/images/arrow_045_small.png" HEIGHT="14" WIDTH="14" BORDER="0" ALT="Submit Form">
                                </form>
```

============================================================================

Site Category
                Site Titles
                Website url's

Comment: You have to fetch the existing data from your database and `echo` it into the textboxes.

Comment: can you give me an example code? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forms that keep their values utilize some sort of peristance, either cookies, or a combination of querying the database for the values.

Either way you would need to then echo our the value inside the `<input>` tag.

Comment: Like this? Do I add id="cat1" so it goes to the correct box?                                                       <input type="text" name="category" value="<?php echo $category; ?>">

Comment: @user1062501, yes you would echo out in this format: `<input type="text" name="category" value="<?php echo $category; ?>">`

Comment: remember if you like the answer you can 'vote up' (or down if you dislike) also the GREEN checkmark sets it as accepted answer.

Comment: I can't vote up yet...can you help me with this? I can repopulate the form, but the form, but it's recreating itself over the page. It's clearly not directed properly. Where exactly does the code go? Thank you again...